# Sum of CRC8 OneWire

Tags: crc, 1wire

Trying to understand `crc8`. This is my calculations:

```
poly 100110001 #  OneWire

bin 00000001 #  1

1.  000000010 << 1 = 000000100
2.  000000100 << 1 = 000001000
3.  000001000 << 1 = 000010000
4.  000010000 << 1 = 000100000
5.  000100000 << 1 = 001000000
6.  001000000 << 1 = 010000000
7.  010000000 << 1 = 100000000
8.  100000000 ^ 100110001 = 000110001 << 1 = 001100010 == 00110001 #  8 digits

crc8 = 0x31 #  online calc true

bin 01000001 #  41

1.  010000010 << 1 = 100000100
2.  100000100 ^ 100110001 = 000110101 << 1 = 001101010
3.  001101010 << 1 = 011010100
4.  011010100 << 1 = 110101000
5.  110101000 ^ 100110001 = 010011001 << 1 = 100110010
6.  100110010 ^ 100110001 = 000000011 << 1 = 000000110
7.  000000110 << 1 = 000001100
8.  000001100 << 1 = 000011000 == 00001100

crc8 = 0xC #  online calc true
```

Now need `crc8` of `141` The first one plus the second. Using online calculator https://ghsi.de/CRC/index.php?Polynom=100110001&Message=141 I see that `crc8` of `141` must be `0xF8`. But `0x31 + 0xC` will be `3D`. Where is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, CRCs don't add like that.  You need to take the register value after running `0x01` through, which gives `0x31`, and use that as the starting register value when feeding `0x41`.  You need to exclusive-or the `0x41` with the `0x31` as the first step, resulting in `0x70`.  Given that, eight steps give you `0xf8` as expected.

However you have not yet arrived at the OneWire CRC-8.  That CRC-8 is computed in the reversed direction, shifting down instead of up and using the polynomial (excluding the x<sup>8</sup>) reversed. Unlike both what you did and what that website does, which is shifting up.  What's more, the message is fed in backwards.

Comment: It worked :) Thx.
`1. 011100000 << 1 = 111000000
2. 111000000 ^ 100110001 = 011110001 << 1 = 111100010
3. 111100010 ^ 100110001 = 011010011 << 1 = 110100110
4. 110100110 ^ 100110001 = 010010111 << 1 = 100101110
5. 100101110 ^ 100110001 = 000011111 << 1 = 000111110
6. 000111110 << 1 = 001111100
7. 001111100 << 1 = 011111000
8. 011111000 << 1 = 111110000 == 11111000`
About OneWire. As I understand  instead of shift left 1, I must shift right 8? If the original message is `123456789`, for OneWire it must be `987654321`. But what to do with poly?

Comment: For each step shift right one, exclusive-oring with the polynomial if the bit shifted out is one.  The polynomial is reversed, so `10001100`.